# Show $r^2$ and $r^3$ can be written as linear combinations of $P(r,3)$, $P(r,2)$, and $P(r,1)$.

Tags: combinatorics

Show how $r^2$ and $r^3$ can be written as linear combinations of $P(r,3)$, $P(r,2)$, and $P(r,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:

$$P(r,3)=(r-2)(r-1)r=r^{3}-3r^{2}+2r$$
$$P(r,2)=(r-1)r=r^{2}-r$$
$$P(r,1)=(r-1)r=r$$

Then $$1\cdot P(r,3)+3\cdot P(r,2)+1\cdot P(r,1)=r^3 $$
and
$$0\cdot P(r,3)+1\cdot P(r,2)+1\cdot P(r,1)=r^2 $$